# How to show/dispose success/failure error messages

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

Suppose a view with a list of users and a link to another view that contains a form to add a new user to the list. You fill the form in, and click submit. Then the server receives that request and tries to insert the record in the database. This could be a success or a failure. In both cases you are redirected to the main view with the users list. Then the success/failure message is displayed along the list of users.

At the moment, when I finish the database transaction, I redirect the user to the main view with a request parameter that holds the message. The main view gets that message and if it's not null, it displays the message.

Altough this works, it has some drawbacks. For example, if the user reloads the view, the message still pops up. So I'm sure this is not the way to do it.

There are more possibilities to do the same but I was wondering what's the most common way to achieve this (saving in session, request attribute instead of request parameter..., and how to dispose the message once is shown.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a flash attribute that can be added prior to the redirect:

1) add RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs to method signature
2) call redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute() to add your message prior to redirecting

See [example in spring docs here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html), there is also an example in PetClinic app

Comment: Thank you very much. Flash attribute was the keyword I needed.